# Discord.py tried to make blacklist system

Tags: python, discord.py, blacklist

I tried to make blacklist system in discord.py

```py
class blackk(commands.CheckFailure): pass

def __global_check_once(ctx):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT ban_id FROM bany WHERE ban_id = {ctx.author.id}")
    r = cursor.fetchone()
    if r is not None:
        raise blackk()
    else:
        return 


@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, blackk):
        await ctx.send("blacklisted")
```

I really need it. Someone know better way to do it (example please)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `__global_check_once` has been replaced by `bot_check_once`.  It should return `True` or `False`.  [You can find a list of Cog special methods here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#special-methods)